# Adding initializers in category

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Im trying to add an init method in a category like this:

```
@interface NSError (message)

+(id)errorWithCode:(NSInteger)code message:(NSString*)message;
-(id)initWithCode:(NSInteger)code message:(NSString*)message;

@end
```

-
    @implementation NSError (message)

```
+(id)errorWithCode:(NSInteger)code message:(NSString*)message;
{
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithCode:code message:message] autorelease];
}

-(id)initWithCode:(NSInteger)code message:(NSString*)message;
{
    NSMutableDictionary * userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [userInfo setValue:message forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

    self = [super initWithDomain:@"some.domain" code:code userInfo:userInfo]; // problem line

    return self;
}

@end
```

But it complais about "super" beeing of class NSObject and not responding to initWithDomain...
I tried casting super to NSError but compiler says it is not allowed.

If I run it, I get "unrecognized selector sent to..." so it's not just a casting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't *inherit* from `NSError`, you *added* new code to the same class. So instead of `super` you should probably be calling `self`.

Comment: but if you replace super with self, how does that work if self hasn't been fully initialized yet?

Comment: It's the same as in a class where you have a designated initialiser and a bunch of convenience initialisers. I'm guessing, but I would imagine that `alloc` sets up enough information for `self` to work in this context.